# Disable Windows login prompt and fail request on non-domain joined machines

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iis

Is there a way to prevent a user's browser from prompting for credentials when using Windows Auth in IIS (7+), in the event a proper NTLM/Kerberos negotiate fails?

Scenarios: Intranet, non-domain machine; Intranet, domain-joined machine, local user; internet, non-domain machine.

Basically I want the request to fail in the event a negotiate fails and requires a prompt, such that the user never sees a prompt. Either it does SSO properly, or it simply fails the request.

Since this is a browser behavior I suspect there's no way to control it from the server side, but I'm open to even client-side approaches as well.

My gut tells me there is no way to control this behavior, but I'm looking for options.

Comment: Are you using? Windows based authentication in your code?

Comment: Yes, but I want the experience to be that the user never sees the prompt. Its perfectly okay to fail the response instead, as we handle that scenario in a different way.